# Add callback listener with Telegram-bot-python

Tags: python, callback, python-telegram-bot

how can I add callbackurl listener with `telegram-bot-python`

I get this error:

> Address already in use

Code:

```py
app = Bottle()
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))
@app.route('/auth/')
def my_listener():..

PORT = os.environ.get('PORT')
updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                          port=int(PORT),
                          url_path=token,
                          webhook_url=f"https://{herokuname}.herokuapp.com/{token}")
updater.idle()
```

Comment: You have PORT assigned twice, the second one will revert to 80, so if you already have a webserver running....

Comment: This was already discussed [here](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/464937). Solutions include having either the `app` handle the Telegram updates ([here](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/464941)) or having the `updater` handle the updates that the `app` was supposed to handle ([here](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/464966))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and it worked

```
from flask import Flask, request
import os
import logging
import telegram
import time
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import CallbackContext, CommandHandler, Updater

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger("test")
token = "token"
herokuname = "name"
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))
updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
bot = updater.bot
update_queue = updater.update_queue
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/' + token, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    update = telegram.update.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), bot)
    logger.info(f"update id is : {update.update_id}")
    update_queue.put(update)
    return 'OK'


def start(update:Update, context:CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text("ok")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    updater._init_thread(dispatcher.start, "dispatcher")
    bot.set_webhook(f"https://{herokuname}.herokuapp.com/{token}")
    time.sleep(5)
    app.run(
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=PORT,
        debug=True
    )
```